# lazarus / delphi (pascal) - writing to txt file without overwriting next time

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I'm using lazarus and I wanted to save to a txt file, information when the program is closed. But each time i reopen the program it overwrites what was there before in the txt file. It would be ok both to write to the next line or even creating a different txt file each time. This is what i have:

```
var
  ...
  s: TStringList;

  s:= TStringList.Create;
  s.Add(datetostr(now));
  s.SaveToFile(datetostr(now)+'.txt');
  s.Free;
```

but i'ts giving me an error

Comment: Open a file stream, seek to the end, save to the stream

Comment: If you have an error you can see what it is. We cannot. Are we to guess? Did you read the error message? Perhaps the date as string has path separators. Why do we need to guess.

Comment: I check through all compiler error messages but couldn't find the "an error" message.

Comment: Depending on your locale your DateToStr result may have slashes in it which would render it invalid as a file name. Use FormatDateTime instead and make sure the result is a proper file name. Also use hours, minutes and seconds in your format so you can run multiple times a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is open your file in append mode, and then add your text. It will put the new data at the end of the file:

```
  AssignFile(tfOut, C_FNAME);

  try
    // Open for append, write and close.
    append(tfOut);

    writeln(tfOut, 'New data for text file');
    writeln(tfOut, 'New informtion should be at the end of the file.');

    CloseFile(tfOut);

  except
    on E: EInOutError do
     writeln('File error. Elaboration: ', E.Message);
  end;
```

Comment: The WriteLn in the except clause would be fine for a console application.  If the op's application is a VCL application it would not.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using tstringlist is:

s: TStringList;

s:= TStringList.Create;

s.loadfromfile( 'myfile.name' );

s.Add( datetostr( now ) );

( or s.text := s.text + lineending + datetostr( now ) )

s.SaveToFile( 'myfile.name' );

s.Free;